# i used Apache drill with MongoDB database i get data from other field but i did not get data by data

Tags: sql, mongodb, apache-drill

```
select * from mongo.test.users where datetime='2022-07-28T05:16:42.877+00:00';
```

i used Apache drill with MongoDB database i get data from other field but  i did not get data by data ..
when i change the date to string then it showing but in date formate i did'nt get any response

Comment: SQL timestamp literals do not use ISO-8601 formatting. Remember that it is Drill that you are writing your query for, even when the storage backend is MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

My guess here is that you have a data type error going on here.  My guess is that the field `datetime` is in fact being interpreted as a date.  Drill doesn't automatically cast strings into timestamps, so in the query above, in your `WHERE` clause, you are effectively comparing a string with a timestamp and hence getting zero results.

To validate this try this query:

```
SELECT typeof(`datetime`) FROM from mongo.test.users LIMIT 1
```

If the result comes back as some sort of timestamp, then to fix this, all you have to do is cast your string to a timestamp as shown below:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE `datetime` = CAST ('<date>' AS TIMESTAMP)
```

Take a look here at the Drill docs for data type conversions: https://drill.apache.org/docs/data-type-conversion/.